# Angular 9: Resizing fires up when scrolling in mobile

Tags: angular, mobile

In my Angular project, I want to change some values when resizing. The problem that I have is that this resizing function fires up every time I scroll on mobile.

Does anyone know how we can avoid this?

Thanks!

```
  onResize(event){
let checkWidth = event.target.innerWidth;

if(checkWidth < 768) {
  this.showLatest = true;
  this.showMost = false;
  this.showMovies = false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was to figure it out, actually, I found a similar solution for jQuery and I just typed it for Angular.

I am posting it here just in case anyone faces the same issue.

```
cachedWidth:any = window.innerWidth;
```

onResize(event){

`let checkWidth = window.innerWidth;

if(checkWidth !== this.cachedWidth){
if(checkWidth < 768) {
//do something on resizing
}
this.cachedWidth = checkWidth;
}
}`